# How to pass data from a controller in templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is the route specified in my file:

```
.state(
  "path", {
    url: "/{path:.*}",
    views: {
      "secondnav": { 
        templateUrl: "/App/View/Partials/_partDetails.html", 
        controller: 'unitDetailsController' },
        "body": {
          controller: 'unitDetailsController',
          templateUrl: function($scope) {
            return "/app/View/unitDetails.html";
          }
        }
      }
    })
```

How to pass data from controller `unitDetailsController` in `templateUrl`?

Comment: data played on the controller's $scope should be available in the template automatically. Is that what you're asking or have I misunderstood the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data like in the following code:

> **ui-router config:**

```
angular
  .module('angularApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
    //
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
      .state('state1', {
        url: "/state1/:id",
        templateUrl: "views/partials/state1.html",
      });
  });
```

> **Template:**

```
<div ng-controller="RowsCtrl">
    <h1>State 1</h1>
    <p>Id: {{id}}</p>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```